# Dealing with badly designed models from third party API

Tags: c#

In company I work for I am forced to use badly designed models from the third party API I have no access to like:

```
class Player
{
    object Id;
    object Name;
}
```

Each time I use these properties I have to cast them to specific type.

```
var name = player.Name.ToString();
var id = (int)player.Id;
```

And I have to lookup the database what the type is.

I was thinking to create exactly the same classes and using something like AutoMapper to map it to my own type each time and create some proxies/wrapper classes over the original ones.

Any solution?

Comment: Have you looked around at other companies? :)

Comment: I suggest to write a coresponding class for each of these classes and add a public constructor which consumes the old class (and wrappes the members of the old class to the members of the actual class).

Comment: Wrapper classes are probably the easiest route. Add an extension method, like `Wrap(this Player)` or something to keep it simple.

Comment: If only looking up the database bothers you, you can simply cache the types ones per type and work in memory.

Comment: You could create [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for the properties you care about, something like: `public static string GetName(this Player p) { return p?.Name?.ToString(); }`

Comment: Thx for suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways I would do this. Either using an extension method or by simply creating your new class with a static Convert method that take the badly designed class as a parameter.

**Example 1:**

```
namespace ExcellentDesignedClasses
{
    public class NewPlayerClass
    {
        public NewPlayerClass(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }

        public static NewPlayerClass Convert(Player player)
        {
            return new NewPlayerClass((int)player.Id, (string)player.Name);
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Example 2: using Extension Methods**

```
namespace ExcellentDesignedClasses
{
    public class NewPlayerClass
    {
        public NewPlayerClass(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ExcellentDesignedClasses.Extensions
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static NewPlayerClass ConvertToNew(this Player player)
        {
            return new NewPlayerClass((int)player.Id, (string)player.Name);
        }
    }
}

namespace MyProgram
{
    using ExcellentDesignedClasses.Extensions;
    public class Main
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            var oldClassStructure = new Player();
            var newClassStructure = oldClassStructure.ConvertToNew();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only negative to using option 1 here involves dependency.  If the model is invoked directly as a parameter in a method or is passed through an interface, you would have to continue using the original, poorly designed object.  If you inherit and override, then anything which takes the poorly designed object will accept the replacement object in its parameters.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is create an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for the properties you care about. The nice thing is it's less work up front: just create an extension method when you find yourself needing to do a cast. You don't have to write any full classes or mapping code. The downside is you have to call a method every time you need a strongly typed property.

For example:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static string GetName(this Player p) 
        { 
            return p.Name?.ToString(); 
        }

        public static int GetId(this Player p) 
        { 
            return Convert.ToInt32(p.Id);
        }
    }   
}
```

Then your code would look like:

```
string name = player.GetName();
int id = player.GetId();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've worked for companies like this.  They're the kind that still ask you in the interview if you know .Net, and you find out they mean version 1.1 on an old instance of Server 2003 they need maintained.   They're the burnt raisins in the Raisin Bran.

Use inheritance to redefine the craptastic models.  That's how I usually fix it.  Then, I return what I want from my objects and stop using the classes I based them on.

ex:

```
    class Player
    {
        public object Id;
        public object Name; 

    }

    class UserPlayer : Player
    {
        public new int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(base.Id);
            }
            set
            {
                base.Id = value;
            }

        }
        public new string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Name.ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                base.Name = value;
            }
        }
   }
```

A runner up idea for when doing the above will get you in trouble because the person who wrote the code still works for the company and has friends or is, worse, your boss: use a static class to process what you want.

```
        public static class ProcessPlayers
        {
            public static int ID(Player p)
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(p.Id);
            }

            public static string Name(Player p)
            {
                return p.Name.ToString();
            }
        }
```

You can also just make new objects that each wrap around `Player` by having a `Player` as a property, but inheriting the object and overriding its properties is likely the better choice.